# How do I make my file copy script using pscp write logs?

Tags: windows, file-copying, pscp

I use pscp command to copy files but it does not write logs. Can anyone please suggest?
Here is the syntax of the pcsp script:

```
pscp C:\Users\jbsmith\directory\*.txt jbsmith@cheyenne.ucar.edu:/glade/u/home/$USER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of psftp command which will server the purpose.

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY"
psftp -b script.txt @ -pw